# Android Xamarin retrieving data from SQLite database returns default objects

Tags: c#, android, list, sqlite, xamarin.android

I have a `list` of objects that I am storing in `SQLite` database and when I want to load the objects in the table into my list, I get the exact amount of object I stored but it's all default objects.
What I tried:

```
string strsql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MyObject");
List<MyObject> list = db.Query<MyObject>(strsql);
```

```
List<MyObject> list = db.Table<MyObject>().ToList();
```

```
List<MyObject> list= new List<MyObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    try
    {
        list.Add(db.Get<MyObject>(i));
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

It's all bring the same result. I don't know why, but it seems like the objects that I get went through the default constructor before and therefore their properties are lost in the database.

Comment: You could use the  **sqlite-net-pcl** NuGet package . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I am using this package and I tried the way they did on this page (with async), but still for the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, my solution for whoever need. I had many members in my class but only one (the primary key) was public, I made every other member public and it worked.